# counting the elements of a list of lists PROLOG

Tags: prolog

I am trying to count the elements of a list of
lists.

I implemented the code in this way:

```
len1([],0).
len1([_X|Xs],N) :- len1(Xs,N1), N is N1+1.

clist([[],[]],0).
clist([Xs,Ys],N):-  len1(Xs,N1),len1(Ys,N2),N is N1+N2.
```

i re-use count element (len1 predicates) in a list, and seems work. 
Anyone can say me if is nice work, very bad or can do this but it s preferable other (without len1).

I dont think is good implementation, and otherwhise seems not generic.

Ad example this work only with list, that contain two list inside. If i want make generic? i think need to use _Xs, but i try to change my code and not working.
in particular i try to change this:

```
clist([Xs,Ys],N):-  len1(Xs,N1),len1(Ys,N2),N is N1+N2.
```

in

```
clist([_Xs],N):-  len1(_Xs,N1),N is N1.
```

and obviously don't work.

Comment: A list of lists, or  an lists that are nested *arbitrary* deep?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well you can apply the *same* trick for your `clist/2` predicate: instead of solving the problem for lists with two elements, you can consider two cases:

1. an empty list `[]`, in which case the total number is of course zero; and
2. a non-empty list `[H|T]`, where `H` is a list, and `T` is the list of remaining lists. In that case we first calculate the length of `H`, we the calculate (through recursion) the sum of the lists in `T` and then sum these together.

So we can implement this as:

```
clist([], 0).
clist([H|T], N) :-
    length(H, HN),
    clist(T, TN),
    N is HN + TN.
```

The above can be improved by using an accumulator: we can define a predicate `clist/3` that has a variable that stores the total number of elements in the list *this* far, in case we reach the end of the list, we unify the answer with that variable, like:

```
clist(L, N) :-
    clist(L, 0, N).

clist([], N, N).
clist([H|T], N1, N) :-
    length(H, HN),
    N2 is N1 + HN,
    clist(T, N2, N).
```

Comment: lenght is predefinite predicate?because for exercise i would implement alone(just for understand how work).  In the "optimization" i understand that you use a sort of cycle like in programming language ..so when i ask to compile a query i need to specify the list of list and the number of elements (number of list inside the list)...right? sorry for more question, but i try to understand well

Comment: @theantomc: well you imlemented a `len1/2` yourself, so you can use it. As for the optimization, we use an [accumulator](http://people.sju.edu/~jhodgson/ai/accums.html), so no, this will generate the total number of elements.

Comment: can i use my len1 like in my example? or is wrong way? For optimization i think must study more on accumulator, i will do and after i try new example with this new element for me. thanks so much for clarify!

Comment: @theantomc: yes, if you replace the `length(H, HN)` call with `len1(H, HN)` it will still work.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you were correct in wanting to *generalize* your definition. Instead of

```erlang
clist([[],[]],0).
```

(well, first, it should be

```erlang
clist( [] , 0).
```

Continuing...) and

```erlang
clist([Xs,Ys], N):-  len1(Xs,N1), len1(Ys,N2), N is N1+N2.
```

which handles *two* lists in a list, change it to

```erlang
clist([Xs|YSs], N):-  len1(Xs,N1), len1(YSs,N2), N is N1+N2.
```

to handle any number of lists in a list. But now the second `len1` is *misapplied*. It receives a list of lists, not just a list as before. Faced with having to handle a list of lists (`YSs`) to be able to handle a list of lists (`[Xs|YSs]`), we're back where we started. Are we, really?

Not quite. We already have the predicate to handle the list of lists -- it's `clist` that we're defining! Wait, what? Do we have it defined yet? We haven't finished writing it down, yes, but we will; and when we've finished writing it down we *will* have it defined. Recursion is a leap of faith:

```erlang
clist([Xs|YSs], N):-  len1(Xs,N1), clist(YSs,N2), N is N1+N2.
```

Moreover, this second list of lists `YSs` is *shorter* than `[Xs|YSs]`. An *that* is the key.

And if the lists were *arbitrarily deeply* nested, the recursion would be

```erlang
clist([XSs|YSs], N):-  clist(XSs,N1), clist(YSs,N2), N is N1+N2.
```

with the appropriately mended base case(s).

*Recursion is a leap of faith:* assume we have the solution already, use it to handle smaller sub-cases of the problem at hand, simply combine the results - there you have it! *The solution* we assumed to have, coming into existence because we used it as if it existed already.

```erlang
recursion(   Whole, Solution ) :-
    problem( Whole,           Shell, NestedCases),
    maplist( recursion,              NestedCases, SolvedParts),
    problem(        Solution, Shell,              SolvedParts).
```

A Russian *matryoshka doll* of problems all the way down, turned into solutions all the way back up from the deepest level. But the point is, we *rely* on *recursion* to handle the inner matryoshka, however many levels *it* may have nested inside her. We only take apart and reassemble the *one* -- the top-most.

Answer (score 0):

```
howMany([],_,0).

howMany([Head|Tail],X,Times):-
    \+(Head = X),
    howMany(Tail,X,Times1),
    Times is Times1.

howMany([Head|Tail],X,Times):-
    Head = X,
    howMany(Tail,X,Times1),
    Times is Times1 +1.
```